# Quicksort not sorting array of long values correctly

Tags: c, sorting, types, quicksort, long-integer

I'm trying to implement a quicksort algorithm to sort an array defined by `long * array`. It sorts most of the values, but not all of them. I feel like there must be an issue with the range of values used but I cannot identify it.

```
void swap(long *a, long *b)
{
    long temp = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = temp;
}

long partition(long * arr, long low, long high) {
  long pivot = arr[high];
  long i = low;
  for (long j = low; j < (high - 1); j++) {
    if (arr[j] < pivot) {
      swap(&arr[i], &arr[j]);
      i++;
    }
  }
  swap(&arr[i], &arr[high]);
  return i;
}

void quickSort(long * arr, long low, long high) {
  if (low < high) {
    long p = partition(arr, low, high);
    quickSort(arr, low, p - 1);
    quickSort(arr, p + 1, high);
  }
}
```

I call `quickSort` with `quickSort(array, 0, size - 1)`. Here's the output when sorting a random array of 15 long values:

```
-482641087233232037
-3864131317804163752
-3090751678944217314
-2010933995968724040
1597984395262413786
2533582178445507721
2959320811908600883
5433974314367983925
-8110790053026736838
4549802945312878540
2821133411822490835
-2345840024589719123
606083409223366793
-4897849740314804917
-8410623358012228580

Starting quicksort.

-8410623358012228580
-3090751678944217314
-3864131317804163752
-2345840024589719123
-2010933995968724040
-8110790053026736838
-482641087233232037
606083409223366793
1597984395262413786
2821133411822490835
2533582178445507721
2959320811908600883
4549802945312878540
5433974314367983925
-4897849740314804917
```

Comment: Change `j < (high - 1)` to `j < high`.

Comment: Thank you Eric, this fixed my issue!

Comment: I think you should delete this question.  It is a simple issue; it is unlikely to help anyone else in the future.